# BIRT Integration - ODA Exception

Tags: birt

My team is using BIRT to handle our clients business logic. Every so often we get an exception in our our logs:

```
18-Dec-2012 11:25:39.163 INFO 
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JndiDataSource.getDriverJndiPropertyFile 
getDriverJndiPropertyFile() java.io.IOException: Unable to locate the installation path of 
the ODA extension (org.eclipse.birt.runtime). The ODA consumer application must specify a 
ResourceIdentifiers in the appContext to resolve the path.
```

We're not sure what causes this error and it seems to be working fine. We have a jdbc connection so we're not sure what would cause this. Any tips or info that we could use to help troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy

```
mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
```

to

```
WEB-INF\platform\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_INSTALLED_VERSION\drivers
```

folder.